# Backlight of built-in display turns off when laptop lid is moved downwards from a certain angle

Tags: nvidia, display, acpi, backlight, lid

I want to prevent backlight of built-in display from turning off when laptop lid is moved downwards ( not even complete close, just downward movement ) from a certain angle via Ubuntu. The external monitor works fine.

As of now only a complete shutdown brings back the backlight to normal. ( not even restart helps ).

It looks like a hardware problem with the lid and the backlight switch.

1. Is there anyway I can inhibit the lid sensor from interfering with the backlight at a hardware level through the OS?
2. Or is there some way I can bring back the backlight to normal after it is turned off from the lid movement.

If helpful, I'm running
Two GPUS : AMD ATI 04:00.0 Cezanne, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile

Comment: Nope. Hardware problem (intermittent connection). Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: Thanks @waltinator